# Passar parametro para um módulo usando WidgetModule (Modular)

Tags: flutter, dart, modularização, bottomnavigationview

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma Pageview com BottomNavigation e gostaria de usar modular nas Pages

Criei os módulos como WidgetMolude ao invés de ChildModule e está tudo ok!!!

```
...
         body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: PageView(
            physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() => currentIndex = index);
            },
            children: <WidgetModule>[
              // Info(widget.store),
              // CustomMap(widget.store.lat, widget.store.long),
              InfoModule(), // Preciso passar parâmetros aqui
              MapModule(), // Preciso passar parâmetros aqui
              InvoicesModule()
            ],
          ),
        ),
...
```

Mas como faço para passar parâmetros?

EDIT:

> O vídeo indicado por Matheus Ribeiro: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#adding-routes sanou as minhas dúvidas. Muito obrigado

Comment: Ao trabalhar com Modular a forma de chamar as telas muda um pouco... A [documentação do package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#adding-routes) (Se é este que está usando, pois não especificou direito qual é) trás bastante informações, acho válido você dar uma olhada. Acredito também que esse vídeo [Flutter Modular - Criando BottomNavigationBar (RouterOutlet)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#adding-routes) irá sanar suas dúvidas.

Comment: Uma dica: De o máximo de informações possíveis em suas perguntas aqui (Que sejam úteis). Por exemplo essa pergunta aqui, você não nos mostrou como está seus Módulos e não sabemos quais parâmetros existem nas suas telas... Assim fica difícil lhe ajudar

Comment: Muito obrigado @MatheusRibeiro, esse vídeo me clareou a mente .. consegui fazer o que eu queria.